# IN operation in realm

Tags: android, realm

I have a total three classes to manage dealer's selected products data.

Classes that extends RealmObject

```
1) Dealers  
     DealerId 
     DealerName

2) Products
     ProductId
     ProductName
3) DealerProduct ( contains the mapping between Dealers's selected product )
    DealerId
    ProudctId
```

now i want to fire a query using realm

```
 select * from Products where productId IN ('P101','P102');
```

is there way to fire a `IN` operation in realm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RealmQuery.or()`

```
RealmResults<Products> products = realm.where(Products.class)
            .equalTo("productId", "P101")
            .or().equalTo("productId", "P102")
            .findAll();
```

Comment: so if i have the whole array with a size of 10 then alsoi have to use above expression like equalTo 10 times ?

Comment: i have finally wrote ` String arr [] = {"C0001" , "C0002" , "C0702"};
        for(int i = 0 ; i< 3 ; i++){

            query.equalTo("dealerID", arr[i]).or();


        }`

Comment: Right, that is not convenient at all... I created an issue in realm-java repo, https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2230 . We will try to make this case easier. Thanks a lot for the feedback!